How to instance primitives in react three fiber?
I have been able to instance a cube made in R3F when I copy this setup, but for my palm element which is a primitive (which is just a low poly palm tree made in blender), it doesn't work - is there any reason why?
Experience.jsx:
const numCubes = 10;
const cubes = Array.from({ length: numCubes }, (_, i) => ({
    position: [
      Math.random() * 200 - 100, // Random x between -100 and 100
      Math.random() * 200 - 100, // Random y between -100 and 100
      0, // z position
    ],
    scale: Math.random() * 90 + 10, // Random scale between 10 and 100
    color: `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`, // Random color
    visible: true,
}));

return (
    <>
 
      {cubes.map((cube, index) => (
        <Cube
          key={index}
          position={cube.position}
          scale={cube.scale}
          color={cube.color}
          visible={cube.visible}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}


I know I'm late, but I faced the exact same issue, and the problem was that you have to clone the scene of your 3D model every time you need to display it!
Here's the answer to your question!

If you’re using useGLTF to load the model and then pass it down the props - you’re only really using a single model at all times. useGLTF has a bit confusing behaviour of loading and caching just a single instance of the model - so if you use or modify the model in more than one component - you’ll be modifying it everywhere (it has it’s pros and cons - but as above, can be a bit confusing.

-mjurczyk
